# Remove all but the first word from a sentence

Tags: actionscript-3, text-segmentation

I need to find a way to take a sentence and remove all its words besides the first.

If the sentence is "Hi my name is dingo"
I need to get only the word "Hi"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var sentence : String = "Hi my name is dingo"
var words : Array = sentence.split( " " );
var firstWord : String = words[ 0 ];
trace( firstWord ) // outputs "Hi"
```

Obviously this only works for simple sentences without punctuation. If you need more complex word parsing you can use regexp:

```
var pattern : RegExp = new RegExp( "\\b.(\\w*).\\b",'gi' );
var words : Array = sentence.match( pattern );
```